# multiple case when para una columna

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo un parámetro de opción de sitio, si la persona escoge el sitio 001 debe tomar los resultados de ev.count pero si escoge el reporte global que seria con ?=[all] deberá tomar los resultados de ev1.s1, tengo error de sintaxis con el case when para esta columna pero no logro encontrar la sintaxis correcta para dos casos en una columna ):

```sql
((case when (ev.site = ?)  then 
     (coalesce(ev.count,0)) else 0 end) or 
(when (? = '[all]') then 
     (coalesce(ev1.s1,0)) else 0 end)) as
Weekly_Actual_of_Patients_Screened,
```

Comment: Antes del segundo `WHEN` colócale el `CASE`. Y además, no sé cómo será tú consulta completa, pero no se necesita un `OR`, el `CASE WHEN` de por sí trabaja similar.

Answer (score 0):

Algo así, todas las condiciones deberían estar en el mismo CASE

```
((case 
    when (ev.site = '001') then 
     (coalesce(ev.count,0))  
    when (ev.site = 'all') then 
     (coalesce(ev1.s1,0)) else 0 end)) 
    as Weekly_Actual_of_Patients_Screened
```